# How to sort "Syntax error in insert into statement"

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, insert-into

For my computer science project I'm using an microsoft acccess database to create a quiz application in visual basic using windows forms. All of my select statements (using oledb to connect to the databse) work correctly and well; but this insert into statement always throws "Syntax error in Insert Into statement" but as far as I can see there is nothing wrong with it. The table in question is called 'Users', with fields 'UserID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Username', 'Password', 'Teacher'; where UserID is an autonumber, teacher is boolean and the rest are strings.

Passwords will be hashed when I'm finished, but so it's easier to test they aren't just yet.

I've already tried entering values for the UserID even though it should automatically increment a value when a new record is entered. And several different methods of creating the insert into command.

```
Using oCmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into Users(FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Teacher) 
    Values(@firstName, @lastName, @username, @password, 0)", myConnection)
    oCmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtFirstName.Text
    oCmd.Parameters.Add("@lastNamee", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtLastName.Text
    oCmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtUsername.Text
    oCmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtPassword.Text
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The 'txt...'.Text are text boxes where the user can enter a string for values they want, and myConnection is the connection to the database which is already open from other commands that have run and terminated. I would expect that a new record would be created in the users table with the values entered in the text boxes; but instead it just throws the error stated above.

Comment: im guessing there is missing space between Users and ( as well as VALUES and (. Debug the sql string to see the ouput - generally itll be obvious what the issue is once you do that

Comment: I suspect `False` is not valid. Does `0` work? (`True` would be `-1`.) Also, you really should use SQL parameters to pass the values otherwise it can go horribly wrong.

Comment: IDK who told you thats a thing? Syntax is not case sensitive?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Passwords should nerver ever be saved as plain text.  They must be salted and hashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason that your SQL command doesn't work is because `Password` should be surrounded by backticks (`) since it is a reserved string. I have had a similar problem in the past and it took me a long time until I realised my mistake.

You should also use parameters to avoid SQL injection. In the end, your code should look like this:

```
Using oCmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO `Users` (FirstName, LastName, Username, `Password`, Teacher) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password, 0)", myConnection)

oCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDBType.VarChar, 63).Value = txtFirstName.Text
oCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDBType.VarChar, 63).Value = txtLastName.Text
oCmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDBType.VarChar, 63).Value = txtUsername.Text
oCmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDBType.VarChar, 63).Value = txtPassword.Text
```

The `63` when adding the parameters is there to describe how many characters the varchar can take. You should change this to the amount that the variables in your database use.

Comment: Actually, it's `password` which is the reserved word; `user` is, but not `users`.

Comment: Oh, and AddWithValue is a poor thing to suggest: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and many more. Updating your answer with a different way of adding the parameters is likely to get you an upvote ;)

Comment: I was not aware of this. Thank you for pointing it out. I have updated my answer to use better parameter addition

Comment: I think the back tick is used in MySql. Since this is OleDb provider, I would guess it is Access where square brackets are used around reserve words. [ ]

Comment: @Mary, I use OleDb for SQL connection, and the back tick works for me

Comment: @Mr Popo, I was just about to run to test, and my laptop dies... I'll get back to you in a bit

Comment: You mean you connect to SqlServer with OleDb? Why would you not use the native provider?

Comment: what is the native provider?

Comment: @MrPopo It works. I had to change the Sqldbtype to oledbtype, I'm not sure why it didn't work with the sql one but yeah. Thanks so much to everyone!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: @MrPopo System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: You are using an `OleDBCommand` object, then using `SqlDbType` with  it.  They do not have the same values as `OleDBType`s (200 vs 22!).  Answer leaves much to be desired (for instance the verbiage still indicates `Password` is the problem)

Comment: @NoneoftheAbove how is `Password` still the problem; I thought I had fixed that problem. As to `OleDBType`, I will update my answer to include it.